# Find tables with columns in Oracle having NUMBER type and some precision

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to find the table (and columns) in Oracle, having data type NUMBER along with decimal precision.
For example, I want to get table names with column defined as "MARKET_RATE NUMBER(4,2)" and NOT the columns defined simply as "AGE NUMBER" (without decimal precision).

I am not sure how exactly tap this query to find such tables(column) details.

Regards.

Comment: Sachin, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, you've accepted only a single answer to all your questions. Are all those answers not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer above the user should be table owner to run the query.
You can also use [ALL_TAB_COLS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1179.htm) table for getting all the columns that user have access

Example query

```
SELECT 
 column_id,
       column_name,
       data_type, 
       data_precision,
       data_scale
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
where 
owner = 'TABLEOWNER'
and data_precision < 10
and Upper(column_name) like '%ID%'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DATA_PRECISION` and `DATA_SCALE` in the `user_tab_cols` or `dba_tab_cols`(if you have privilege). Something like this

```
select column_id,
       column_name,
       data_type, 
       data_precision,
       data_scale
from user_tab_cols col
join user_tables tab on col.table_name = tab.table_name
where data_type ='NUMBER'
and data_precision is not null and data_scale is not null
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ba7b9c42855d0dba309438887208607)

Comment: the query works. but the user who run the query should be table owner